# MySQL: Excluding items in the same table collected in a subquery

Tags: mysql

What I'm trying to accomplish here didn't seem all too difficult, and in execution I don't see anything I'm doing wrong, but I'm getting some results that should negated from the result set.

I'm writing this on my phone so please excuse me while I write this stuff out by hand:

The table is called "requests", and in the program people can sign up to accept a request. A specific request by the client is to hide from users that have already accepted a request.

Here's the catch 22: 
A request is based off a specific entity from another table, and one can post multiple requests per base entity. Basically removing duplicates of said entity from the system, and I figured a decent way to handle this is to have a new associative row known as a request which contains a unique id, the account id of the requestor, the entity id of the entity the request is based on, a account id field for the acceptor of that particular row of available requests.

As you can see it starts getting a bit messy in explanation but please keep in mind that this is a pretty late change and can't afford to change the system around at this stage.

So here's the query as I best remember:

SELECT 
  *
FROM 
  requests 
WHERE 
  completed = 0 AND 
  entity_id != ANY (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(entity_id) WHERE accepted_account_id = '8')

8 is my account ID in the system, there are 8 base entities in the system (all posted from the same account, 7) with 2 of those entities having requests based off of them, the first has 4 requests, and the second has 16 requests. So 20 request rows in the requests table. 
As a user, I have accepted a single request on both entities in the system. So on two rows in the requests table, 
RequestID of 1 with Entity ID 1 with Acceptor Account ID of 8
And 
RequestID of 5 with Entity ID 3 with Acceptor Account ID of 8

while all other rows contain a null field for acceptor_account_id

I am trying to simply negate whole entity_ids from the result set, so as not to mess up the pagination going on in the same query (I'm not interested in separating the query, I'm 150% positive this can all be done in one query)

Please if anyones got any questions, please let me know, as this is urgent :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SELECT * FROM requests WHERE completed = 0 AND entity_id NOT IN (SELECT entity_id WHERE accepted_account_id = '8' GROUP BY entity_id)`

Comment: GROUP BY.... GROUP BY... GROUP BY!! *slams face into desk* .... so much pain and turmoil... and I was only missing the GROUP BY for the group_concat function. I had been so fixated on the operand I negated to think that the subquery was actually wrong :( Your a life saver man! (I had tried everything I could think of for the operand including NOT IN but was obviously still not working) Thanks for the speedy response!